# Anyone working on rough volatility modelling? Need relevant books to read

Tags: volatility, stochastic-volatility

Just wondering if there is anyone working in the field of rough volatility?

I know the rough volatility modelling is quite new in the field. Can I get some books recommendation to go through?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any books about this topic, but the rough volatility network is a good starting point. There you will find nearly all the relevant papers. https://sites.google.com/site/roughvol/home/risks-1

Comment: I have actually looked at this and read some of them. Thanks for the useful pointers!